# PHP Post and Conditionals Error

Tags: php, mysql, database, post, conditional-statements

Ok, so my site has a link where you can search up users and go to their profile. You type a username and on the next page, it tells you if the username exists or not, and gives you a link. I think I have coded everything correctly, but apparently not.

Here is what happens: (my website echoes two pages, one if you are logged in and one if you are not logged in). If you are logged in AND you type a real username, then it will correctly display the text I want it to and the link. However, if you type a fake username when logged in, it just says the default text, not the text I necessarily want for this page.

When you are not logged in, it only displays the default text, no matter what you type.

Can someone help me and look at this code?

Default text for displaytext:

```
$displaytext = "Error";

$srstrSQL = "SELECT * FROM Users_For_CoinAwards WHERE Username = '$usersearched'";

$rs3 = mysql_query($srstrSQL, $connection);

while($row3 = mysql_fetch_array($rs3)){

if ($row3['Username'] == $usersearched)

{

$displaytext = "The user " . $row3["Username"] . " has been found. Please click on the below link to visit their profile.";

$displaylink = "<a href='http://www.coinawards.net63.net/user/" . $row3['Username'] . ".php' id='displaylink'>" . $row3['Username'] . "</a>";

}

else

{

$displaytext = "Sorry, the user " . $row3["Username"] . " was not found. Please check your query and try again.";

}

}

$row3 = mysql_fetch_array($rs3); print_r($row3);
```

Ok, and here is the part where it displays the text:

' . $displaytext . '

I double checked to make sure that the code above is the same if you are logged in or not, however the results still differ.

EDIT:

you can see what his happening for yourself at http://www.coinawards.net63.net/

Just click on the yellow 'User Search' button and type in a wierd random assortment of characters.

It will take you to the new page with the code below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, try this. And please try $row[] with double or single quotes, you are mixing the two.

```
$srstrSQL = "SELECT * FROM Users_For_CoinAwards WHERE Username = '$usersearched' ";

$rs3 = mysql_query($srstrSQL, $connection);

while($row3 = mysql_fetch_array($rs3)){

 $displaytext = "Error";

if (mysql_num_rows($rs3) == 1)

{

echo $displaytext ."The user " . $row3["Username"] . " has been found. Please click on the below link to visit their profile.";

echo $displaylink ."<a href='http://www.coinawards.net63.net/user/" . $row3['Username'] . ".php' id='displaylink'>" . $row3['Username'] . "</a>";

}

else

{

echo $displaytext."Sorry, the user " . $row3["Username"] . " was not found. Please check your query and try again.";

}

}

$row3 = mysql_fetch_array($rs3); print_r($row3);
```

Comment: This should work but it doesn't, I don't know why and that is really annoying.

Comment: This will tell you if you have problem with mysql
 `$rs3 = mysql_query($srstrSQL, $connection) or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: It just does the same thing as last time... it only works if you are logged in and type a real user

Comment: I don't think I have errors with those statements because I have other queries using the same connection and they work.

Comment: Ok, I have revised it, try copy and paste now. It should definitely work better now.

Comment: ...That still doesn't work... i appreciate your help though... do you have any ideas of why it might work that doesn't have to include the code? Maybe something like an infrastructure problem...

Comment: I think the problem is with the way you have explained it. You are definitely missing something, perhaps you have forgotten to post all the necessary codes here

Answer (score 1):

```
else if ($row3['Username'] !== $usersearched)
```

should be

```
else if ($row3['Username'] != $usersearched)
```

Comment: I fixed that, it still didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

First off **STOP** using mysql_* is no longer maintained and has been recommended that you no longer use that in new projects please look into either pdo or mysqli as seen here http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

the issue i could see is that you are not checking to see if your query returns any results which is why your conditional is only returning one result.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what to use in its place that guide is the most confusing thing on Earth.

Comment: this is a very good one for pdo for beginners http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a binary condition (i.e. the user exists or *does not* exist there is no need for the `else if ($row3['Username'] != $usersearched)` at all. Replace that with `else`.

```
while($row3 = mysql_fetch_array($rs3)){

    if ($row3['Username'] == $usersearched){

        ... Your code here ...


    }else{

        $displaytext = "Sorry, the user " . $usersearched . " was not found. Please check your query and try again.";

    }

}
```

Comment: Can you update your question with the full code that you're using?